# Extract strings upto special character

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract only strings upto certain point.
For example,

```
asd <- 'company_F42542'
```

Expected output

```
new_asd
'F42542'
```

Comment: `gsub(".*\\_", "", asd) `?

Comment: @Friede actually you don't need ` \\ ` to escape `_` :P

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub`

```
> sub(".*_", "", asd)
[1] "F42542"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few alternatives that do not use regular expressions.  The first gives a data frame and the rest give a vector result.

```
read.table(text = asd, sep = "_", col.names = c(NA, "new_asd"),
  colClasses = c("NULL", NA))
##   new_asd
## 1  F42542

sapply(strsplit(asd, "_", fixed = TRUE), "[", 2)
## [1] "F42542" 

library(stringr)
asd %>% chartr("_", " ", .) %>% word(2)
## "F42542"
```

If you want a named scalar then try these

```
asd |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = "_", col.names = c(NA, "new_asd"),
    colClasses = c("NULL", NA)) |>
  unlist()
##  new_asd 
## "F42542" 

strsplit(asd, "_", fixed = TRUE)[[1:2]] |> setNames("new_asd")
##  new_asd 
## "F42542" 

library(stringr)
asd %>% chartr("_", " ", .) %>% word(2) %>% setNames("new_asd")
##  new_asd 
## "F42542"
```